# Server behind private network

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, iptables, nat

I saw a few posts regarding this already but non match my case exactly. I have the following setup:
A VM with a public IP address 1.1.1.1(eth0).
This machine also has a private interface. The private IP address is 2.2.2.2, eth1. On the same VMware machine I have another VM which only has a private interface(ip 2.2.2.3, eth0) with a private IP address. I am looking to access the internet through that private interface VMware machine. That machine also has RDP set up on a port, I have the following rules which work for the remote connection, but public traffic on that machine does not work. The RDP session is on port 1337.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m comment --comment "Accept to forward rdp return traffic" -s 2.2.2.3 -m tcp -p tcp --sport 1337 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1337 -m comment --comment "redirect pkts to virtual machine" -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.3:1337
iptables -I FORWARD -d PUBLIC.IP.1.1.1.1 -m comment --comment "Accept to forward rdp traffic" -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "NAT the src ip" -d 2.2.2.3 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I fixed it myself. This was my solution:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT 2.2.2.3:1337
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d PUBLICIP --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.3:1337
iptables -A FORWARD -d 2.2.2.3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Please, don't put code in comment, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself. This was my solution in case anyone has the same problem:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT 2.2.2.3:1337
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d PUBLICIP --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.3:1337
iptables -A FORWARD -d 2.2.2.3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```